# Chrony sources are with unknown address

Tags: fedora, chrony

I'm trying to setup chrony but it's not working.
I start the service using one of the following command:

```
 sudo systemctl stop chronyd; sudo systemctl start chronyd
 sudo systemctl restart chronyd
```

timedatectl says I'm not synched

```
 timedatectl
 Local time: Tue 2019-11-05 08:04:47 CET
 Universal time: Tue 2019-11-05 07:04:47 UTC
 RTC time: Tue 2019-11-05 07:04:47
 Time zone: Europe/Zurich (CET, +0100)
 System clock synchronized: no
 NTP service: active
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Somehow chrony cannot seem to resolve my source (I'm using the default sources provided on Fedora)

```
chronyc activity             
200 OK
0 sources online
0 sources offline
0 sources doing burst (return to online)
0 sources doing burst (return to offline)
1 sources with unknown address

chronyc sources
210 Number of sources = 0
```

My config file (/etc/chrony.conf)

```
# Use public servers from the pool.ntp.org project.
# Please consider joining the pool (http://www.pool.ntp.org/join.html).
pool 2.fedora.pool.ntp.org iburst

# Record the rate at which the system clock gains/losses time.
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift

# Allow the system clock to be stepped in the first three updates
# if its offset is larger than 1 second.
makestep 1.0 3

# Enable kernel synchronization of the real-time clock (RTC).
rtcsync

# Enable hardware timestamping on all interfaces that support it.
#hwtimestamp *

# Increase the minimum number of selectable sources required to adjust
# the system clock.
#minsources 2

# Allow NTP client access from local network.
#allow 192.168.0.0/16

# Serve time even if not synchronized to a time source.
#local stratum 10

# Specify file containing keys for NTP authentication.
keyfile /etc/chrony.keys

# Get TAI-UTC offset and leap seconds from the system tz database.
leapsectz right/UTC

# Specify directory for log files.
logdir /var/log/chrony

# Select which information is logged.
#log measurements statistics tracking
```

The strangest thing is if I stop the daemon and run chronyd by hand then it works.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/chronyd -d -d > chronyd.out

chronyc activity
200 OK
4 sources online
0 sources offline
0 sources doing burst (return to online)
0 sources doing burst (return to offline)
0 sources with unknown address

chronyc sources
210 Number of sources = 4
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample               
===============================================================================
^+ ns1.nexellent.net             2   6    77    37  +2998us[+2998us] +/-   13ms
^* 162.159.200.1                 3   6    77    38  +1348us[+2529us] +/-   16ms
^- mirror.tillo.ch               2   6    72   177  -1754us[ +375us] +/-   24ms
^- ntp0.as34288.net              2   6    75    50   +729us[ +729us] +/-   11ms
```

Any help to resolve this issue would be welcome.

Comment: What's the name (and location) of the configuration file that you're editing? How are you running it "normally"? It looks like the attempt you're running "by hand" is using a different configuration file.

Comment: @roaima I edited my post, the file I'm editing is /etc/chrony.conf

Comment: And how are you restarting the chrony daemon each time?

Comment: @roaima sudo systemctl stop chronyd; sudo systemctl start chronyd or sudo systemctl restart chronyd

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you've resolved this by now - but if anyone else is having the same problem:

SELinux blocks resolver access from chronyd, simply disabling it allows you to test if this is the cause or add an exception.